# How to loop through and check the xbox controller state in uwp c#

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I want to read the xbox controller joystick values in a c# uwp. I got the c# code for reading the values but how do I loop to check the values.

I have looked it up but the code is for c++.

```
void Game::Loop()
{
// move previous newReading into oldReading before getting next newReading
oldReading = newReading, newReading = gamepad.GetCurrentReading();

// process device readings using buttonJustPressed/buttonJustReleased (see 
below)
}
```

Can you please provide a c# alternative to the above code.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve here. Could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is available for C# as well (Windows.Gaming.Input), and the function is still [GetCurrentReading()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad.getcurrentreading#Windows_Gaming_Input_Gamepad_GetCurrentReading).

This sample in C++ is a sample of a generic game loop, and was merely there to illustrate part of the main game loop should grab the latest inputs and use them.  The way a game loop is implemented is up to the developer and the game engine they are using, be it Unreal, Unity, etc. There's no existing C# alternative.